# How to add spaces to a string to make string have 6 characters

Tags: c#

I need to make a string to have a fixed 6 character. My original string length is smaller than 6, so I need to add space to and the end of my string. Here's my code

```
par = Math.Round(par / 1000, 0);
parFormat = par.ToString() + new string(' ', 6 - par.ToString().Length);
```

I got "count cannot be negative" error message.

Comment: If you get "count cannot be negative", my guess is your original string is, in fact, longer than 6 characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to do this is using String.PadRight:

```
parFormat = par.ToString().PadRight(6);
```

In your method, you could have a int much greater than 6 digits long. This would return a negative length when performing your own pad function. You could also use:

```
par = Math.Round(par / 1000, 0);

parFormat = par.ToString() + new string(' ', Math.Max(0, 6 - par.ToString().Length));
```

To make sure you don't go negative. Using `PadRight` will be much easier though!

MSDN for PadRight: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PadRight()` function to add the specified character to the right of the string for the remianing length.

```
parFormat = par.ToString().PadRight(6,' ');
```

Note: by default `PadRight()` adds space so you can use PadRight with single parameter as below:

```
parFormat = par.ToString().PadRight(6);
```

Comment: Adds spaces by default

Comment: @PseudoNym01: yup , but i think this overloaded version is more readable :)

Comment: @PseudoNym01: You meant to say there exists another overloaded method which adds spaces by default. It must be noted that since the asker wasn't aware of the existence of the `string.PadRight` overload group it is maybe for the best to point out the more general method. It's more pedagogical. Also: Searchers of answers that will google the words of the question's title will most certainly be unaware about those methods also. There is no performance gain in using the shorter overload (disassemble `mscorlib.dll` if you thought otherwise). Also: optimisation is the least concern of the novice.

Comment: @EduardDumitru fair point, however I'm drawing on an experience in college where it was a revelation to us (group of students within a programming class) that C++ had a built in tree/list/stack class we could make use of instead of having to roll our own. If it isn't indicated that the shorter default version of the function already does what is desired then it needlessly adds complexity and time to the source code. Therefore I think both showing how to manually add spaces and mentioning it does this by default both together is the best possible answer.